# Can not run exe packed by pyinstaller

Tags: python

I use windows 10 and python2.7.
I have use PyInstaller to pack a program into exe. But I can not run the .exe file.
error:

```
   raise FileNotFoundError('Tcl data directory "%s" not found.' % (tcldir))
IOError: Tcl data directory "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI10~1\tcl" not 
found.
[4072] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter
```

Answer (score 0):

That's python error which means your program is running. 
Check your code to see why it does not find the file you are mentioning.

Note: If you use relative paths consider that it matters where the `.exe` file is executed.
This is the process home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following command:

```
pyinstaller main.py --add-data 'tcl;./tcl' #linux separator use 'tcl:./tcl'
```

Note: left 'tcl' is in the main.py's directory, right 'tcl' is target directory which is exe genrated directory. if right 'tcl' not existing will be created!